# Known deployments or users of Stack Exchange Data Explorer source?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Do we know of any known installations of the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer code](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/) out in the wild?

Comment: I have a copy running on my local machine, but my desktop is pretty tame.

Comment: @TimStone, do you have a public address for your copy perhaps? (or screenshots?)  I will end up installing it myself one day, but would like to see how it looks out of the box mapped to some other db.  It would also be nice to have a place like this to list some nice example implementations.

Comment: I actually have a local copy for the purposes of doing Data Explorer development, so it's mapped to a database that's based on the data dump (so basically what the live Data Explorer uses), so that's probably not what you were hoping for I'm afraid